# How to compare two columns in Excel with a conditional IF statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have three columns that have some expense figures: Actual (column A), Budget (column B), Variance (column C):

For these expenses, if Actual is greater than Budget, I want the variance column result/formula to be **Budget minus Actual**. But if Actual is less that Budget, I want the variance column result/formula to be **Actual minus Budget**.

I have tried the following, but this is a new field for me so I would really appreciate your assistance. This is what I have tried, but it doesn’t work as expected:

```
=IF(G5>H5,G5-H5,H5-G5)
```

What is the Excel formula/syntax for this?

Comment: Based on the description the formula in cell C5 should be `=IF(A5>B5,A5-B5,B5-A5)` and not referring to columns G and H. As an alternative use `ABS(A5-B5)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this input, let me give it a shot and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with an IF formula you'll need to make 2 changes:

- If the actuals & budget are in columns A & B, respectively (this is what's stated in the question), you'll need to sue columns A & B rather than columns G & H in the formula.
- It looks like you want a negative number in all cases? If so, you'll need to swap the order in your formula: =IF(A5>B5,B5-A5,A5-B5)

Here's an example, with the formula bar showing the formula in cell C5: [image: Example]

---

I also had the same thought gns100 shared in a comment -- you can write an even simpler formula using absolute value -- though if you want all your variances to be negative numbers, you'll need to do =-ABS(A5-B5).